# Compute word count with data.table in R by a value

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to data.table, I have a dataset with person names and countries, and I want to know the most frequent names by country.

The dataset looks like this:

```
DT <- data.table(person_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
           person_name = c('John Smith', 'Marty Mcfly', 'Amélie Poulain', 'John Wick', 'Clark Kent', 'Marcel Poulain'),
           person_ctry = c('US', 'US', 'FR', 'US', 'US', 'FR')
           )
```

I would like to obtain a data.table like this:

```
person_ctry word     count
US          John     2
US          Smith    1
US          Marty    1
FR          Poulain  2
FR          Amélie   1
....
```

I tried this:

```
all_names <- DT[, lapply(.(person_name), paste0, collapse=" "), by=person_ctry]

wordcount <- function(str) {
  as.data.frame(table(unlist( strsplit(str, "\ ") )))
}
all_names[, c("word","count") := wordcount(V1), by=person_ctry]
```

But the last line gives an error saying RHS doesn't match LHS length exactly. However, I don't know how to correct it. Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified approach to count those words:

```
DT[, .(word = unlist(strsplit(person_name, '\\s+'), use.names = FALSE)), 
   by = .(person_ctry)][, .(count = .N), by = .(person_ctry, word)]

 #     person_ctry    word count
 #  1:          US    John     2
 #  2:          US   Smith     1
 #  3:          US   Marty     1
 #  4:          US   Mcfly     1
 #  5:          US    Wick     1
 #  6:          US   Clark     1
 #  7:          US    Kent     1
 #  8:          FR  Amélie     1
 #  9:          FR Poulain     2
 # 10:          FR  Marcel     1
```

The approach has two steps:

- split the words (names) at spaces, do this by country to create an intermediate data.table
- count the number of rows per unique word in each country using data.tables special `.N` function

I combined both steps using a chain of `[]`